# Where to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have the following question (code omitted):

> I have tried to port a php difference engine to javascript as a practice exercise. It does not work, and returns `undefinedundefinedundefined`. I have checked through it more than once and I cannot see where I have gone wrong. The original code and my code is below:
>   
> `code here........`

Am I right in thinking that Stack Overflow is the best place, or is there another place for questions about this kind of thing?

I am new here (meta stack overflow).

update:

I have a suspicion that I have done the foreach loops in correctly. Is there Any way to emulate a foreach php loop in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a great fit on any SE site in its current form, as it looks like you're planning to just show a huge pile of code and ask why it doesn't work. You can try doing that, and maybe you find a kind soul willing to help you, but it's often not really well received - bear in mind that Stack Overflow has about 5600 new questions *per day.*

If you try to isolate in a bit more detail where *exactly* things go wrong where and asking about that *specifically*, it will work fine on Stack Overflow.

Either way, thanks for asking beforehand!

Comment: How should I adjust the question to make it more suitable if I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: @starbeam did debugging not tell you where things go wrong? Can you post a link to a JSFiddle so we can take a look?

Comment: @starbeam that's a *lot* of code. Can you really not pinpoint a more detailed problem description than "it doesn't work"? In that form, it's likely to be closed IMO - but you're free to try and ask it anyway of course

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service; you don't just post a blob of code and expect us to find the problem. You need to expend effort to *localize* the problem using available debugging tools.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs: Yes, because giving up is likely to solve the problem. Honestly, if debugging an application discourages you that much, you won't make a very good programmer; debugging a fair portion of what what most programmers do.

Comment: To start, just run a debugger. If you have no utter idea what a debugger is and how it can be useful, then I'd start learning what a debugger is and how it can be useful. *Then* you can start using it to isolate your problem. Basically, a debugger allows you to execute code in realtime/controlled/step-by-step where you can explore all variables in the heap and the call stack and so on so that you can track what exactly all is (not) happening.

Comment: @Chichiray Thanks for the tip! It seems simple but sometimes I miss that kind of thing. Thank you again!